# Using Boss RC-600 as 3 instrument inputs and 3 instrument outputs

Tags: looping

I am working on a project where we will be using one guitar into a 3-way switcher and then that will go Output 1 to a Marshall Cab,  output 2 to an Orange Cab, output 3 to a bass cab. Each chain has its own series of effects pedals. Currently we are using two side by side ditto pedals for looping but we want a pedal that can do all three under the same clock and preferably all within one unit.

I need a looper that has three inputs and 3 outputs.

So far my research has led me to this pedal. I have seen that you can take the instrument stereo inputs and split them, and that you can select which is going to which output Main, sub 1, sub 2. Has anyone tried this? I want to know if I can make it so the Left of instrument 1  goes to the Left of Main, the Right of instrument 1 goes to Sub 1, and the Left of Instrument 2 goes to sub 2.

Comment: If computers are authorised, a combination of Jack and SooperLooper (and a sound card) will work guaranteed.

Comment: Just to get ahead of the close-votes: Questions about gear recommendations [aren't covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so if the question leans to "Is this the right pedal for the job and if not what is" that would be off-topic, but "What's the best way in general to go about this goal" would be on.

Comment: The signal chain and the goals are unclear to me. Perhaps a solution could be to mike all three cabs, mix the signal, feed into the looper and send to the PA?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the manual for the pedal and reading it? It looks complex enough that you will have to read it in any case.